# Negative Lookahead matching

Tags: python, regex

I have this string:

```
maria 10 years maria 10 maria10 maria10 years
```

And would like to match `maria` followed by `10` when the next word is not `years`. I tried like this:

```
\maria\s?[0-9]+(?!years)
```

But it matches `maria 10` even if the next word is `year`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just forgot the space before `years`:

```
In [1]: import re
In [2]: s = "maria 10 years maria 10 maria10 maria10 years"
In [3]: re.findall(r"(\maria\s?[0-9]+)\s(?!years)", s)
Out[3]: ['maria 10', 'maria10']
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
maria\s*[0-9]+\s+(?!years)
```

Since `years` doesn't immediately follow `"maria 10"` (there is a whitespace)

#### Demo: http://regex101.com/r/dI2lA1

Comment: It did not work here... you were right about the white space... in this case do you know why \maria\s?[0-9]+(?!\syears) wouldnt work? thanks!

Comment: Not with the Python `re` module they won't.

Comment: @user2950162: Edited regex and added a regex demo

Comment: @sudo_O: That is `maria 10` after `years` see this demo: http://ideone.com/oFkFLN